# Having difficulty catching postgresql exception in sequel/ruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I have postgresql table that has somekind of unique constraint.

I have ruby script that will update this table.
The ruby script should be able to switch to UPDATE instead of INSERT
when this kind of error occured:
`PGError: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint`

CMIIW, sequel seems cannot catch this exception??

Anyway,sample code below is something that I would like to see to work but apparently not:

```
@myarray.each do |x|
        fresh_ds = DB["INSERT INTO mytable (id, col_foo) values ('#{x}' ,'#{myhash[x]}')"] 
        result = fresh_ds.insert

        catch Sequel::Error do

            fresh_ds = DB["UPDATE mytable set col_foo = '#{myhash[x]} where id = #{x}"]
            result = fresh_ds.update

        end

end
```

Maybe my ruby code is wrong or I missed something I don't know.
Any solution?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
code below  works, the error is caught when unique constraint is violated.

```
@myarray.each do |x|
    begin
      # INSERT CODE
    rescue Sequel::Error
      # UPDATE CODE
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try-catch in Ruby [goes like this](http://ruby.activeventure.com/programmingruby/book/tut_exceptions.html):

```
begin
...
rescue ExceptionClass => ex
...
end
```

Another thing is that you should use Sequel's parameter interpolation instead of making whole query by hand (mainly because of SQL injection):

```
fresh_ds = DB["INSERT INTO mytable (id, col_foo) values (? ,?)", x, myhash[x]]
```

PS:

As others already pointed out, there are other, arguably better, ways to perform "insert or update". Generally, exceptions are meant for, er, exceptions, i.e. conditions that shouldn't normally happen during course of execution. Your case is more of `if` sort, so I would either first use `SELECT` to check whether row already exists, or, rather, try `UPDATE` first and see the number of changed rows and perform `INSERT` if it is zero.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know begin/rescue/end can be used inside a loop also appreciated for the sql injection avoidance tips.

Comment: More idiomatically: `DB[:mytable].insert :id=>x, :col_foo => myhash[x]` and then `DB[:mytable].filter( :id=>x ).update( :col_foo => myhash[x] )`

Comment: ok guys I know the code is one fugly fragile code, will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate path to solve this problem uses Sequel::Model's [`find_or_create`](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/ClassMethods.html#M000256) method:

> `find_or_create (cond, &block)`
>
> Like find but invokes create with given conditions when record does not exist. Unlike find in that the block used in this method is not passed to find, but instead is passed to create only if find does not return an object.